# Django. How can I render a class method?

Tags: django, django-templates

I apologize for the stupid question.
This is my very first experience with OOP.

- Question 1: How can I render the value, which is calculated in my
  class method `fseries(self)`? I understand that the problem is with parenthesis. I have a number of similar calculated values, which need to be rendered. Shall I calculate / define all
  these values in class methods or somehow else?
- Question 2: Is it correct that I am getting the object via
  `get_object_or_404(afc_series, valuefg = self.series)` or shall I use
  another construction?

```
#views.py
...
    myfilter = Ksf_filter(name="mysuperfilter_XXX", series="ABCDE")
    #just testing correctness
    print(myfilter.name)
    print(myfilter.fseries())
    print(myfilter.fseries().valueecp)
    context = {'myfilter':myfilter,}
    return render(request, 'af/size/01_kss_size2.html', context)
```

```
#ksf_filter.py
from af.models import afc_series
from django.shortcuts import  get_object_or_404

class Ksf_filter:
    def __init__(self, name, series):
        self.name = name
        self.series = series

    def fseries(self):
        return get_object_or_404(afc_series, valuefg = self.series)
```

```
#template.html
{{myfilter.name}} ///// {{myfilter.fseries()}} //// {{myfilter.fseries().valueecp}})
```

This is the error message, I get.

```
#Error_msg  
TemplateSyntaxError at /ru/af/n01_size_kss/
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'myfilter.fseries()'
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/ru/af/n01_size_kss/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'myfilter.fseries()'
```

Thank you

Comment: `{{ myfilter.fseries }}`. Django templates automatically call a callable.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I am really too stupid. ((

Answer (score 1):

Django template variables automatically call a callable *without* extra parameters. So you can render this with:

```
{{ myfilter.fseries }} {{ myfilter.fseries.valueecp }}
```

The Django template language is *deliberately* restricted to do more advanced function calls to prevent people from writing business logic in the templates.

In case you need more advanced processing, you normally do this in the *view*. You can also use more extended template language like [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/).

> Question 2: Is it correct that I am getting the object via `get_object_or_404(afc_series, valuefg = self.series)` or shall I use another construction?

If `valuefg` is unique, then this can be used as an "identifier". Using `get_object_or_404` is then a good idea, since it returns a 404 in case it can not find the element. You however should make sure that there is (at most) *one* value that can match.